# Axios without a full URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I have a single web page application in the domain: sxxxcex-cxxfc.web.app

And the server, from which I will consume the API is at xx.x2.xx.74: 8000

To login with Axios, I do the following:

```
 const url='xx.x2.xx.74:8000/login/'

axios.get(url+user+"/"+password)
 .then((res: { data: any; }) => {
     setIngresar(false);
     const resquest = res.data;
     if(resquest=="invalid user"){
       console.log(resquest);
     }
     else{
        setItem("isRegistered", resquest[0].user);
     }
  }).catch((err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
    setIngresar(false)
  })
```

The full path of the GET method is

https://sxxxcex-cxxfc.web.app/xx.x2.xx.74:8000/login/theUSer/ThePassword

But it should be:

https: //xx.x2.xx.74: 8000 / login / theUSer / ThePassword

Could someone tell me how to send this last url without the sxxxcex-cxxfc.web.app?

Comment: Did you try like this? const url = 'https: //xx.x2.xx.74: 8000/login'; and then your code.

Comment: Yes I did. I tried that

Comment: Does not that work?

Comment: `https://sxxxcex-cxxfc.web.app/xx.x2.xx.74:8000/login/theUSer/ThePassword` is a relative path axios comes up with because there is no `https://` before `'xx.x2.xx.74:8000/login/'`

Comment: Hi @codemonkey. I know. but it sends request to another domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you didn't add "https://" in the url.
So when you send request by axios, it try to find urls in the same domain.
If you try your code in local, the url should be https://localhost:3000/xx.x2.xx.74.8000/login/theUSer/ThePassword.
So you should add "https://" in front of url like this.

```
url = 'https://xx.x2.xx.74: 8000/login';
axios.get(url+user+"/"+password)
 .then((res: { data: any; }) => {
     setIngresar(false);
     const resquest = res.data;
     if(resquest=="invalid user"){
       console.log(resquest);
     }
     else{
        setItem("isRegistered", resquest[0].user);
     }
  }).catch((err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
    setIngresar(false)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks. Can it be http? and not https?

Comment: Yes. It's up to your api.

Comment: As far as javascript is concerned, you can use either http or https. However, web browsers increasingly require https everywhere for your application to be considered secure and trusted. So you might see http requests made by javascript getting blocked by the web browser.

Comment: It is possible that as the application, that is a firebase domain is https when placing http I add axios to the server domain by prepending https?